# Hosting modules internally

Tags: 7

Our company is looking to use Drupal as a platform going forward. We plan on making some modules for in house use only i.e. A module to talk to our holiday system. We wanted to know the best way to host these internally so people can browse the modules. Is it possible to get Drupal to report when a custom module is out of date?

Comment: For Drupal 6, there is the Features Update Server: http://drupal.org/project/fserver.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please try removing "best" from your question, as we try to avoid opinions here. Best you can do to stay on-topic is to simply ask for the ways, and then choose - because there is no "best way". There may be a "way best for you". We may help with "the way" part, but not the "for you" part of issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want somewhere to host modules you could use distributed version control such as Git or Mercurial to store them in a repository.

You can then use [drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) make to build the site with modules hosted on drupal.org and from your repository.